# Pandas data frame. Column consistency. Bring integer values to fixed length

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I open the .tsv file in a following way:

```
cols = ['movie id','movie title','genre']
movies = pd.read_csv('movies.dat', sep='::', index_col=False, names=cols, encoding="UTF-8",)

+---+----------+-------------------------------------+
|   | movie id |             movie title             |
+---+----------+-------------------------------------+
| 0 |        8 | La sortie des usines Lumière (1895) |
| 1 |       12 | The Arrival of a Train (1896)       |
| 2 |       91 | Le manoir du diable (1896)          |
| 3 |      417 | Le voyage dans la lune (1902)       |
+---+----------+-------------------------------------+
```

In the initial .tsv file all the values in movie id column are fixed length and start with 0, for example 0000008, 0000012, 0000091, 0000417.

I need to merge this column later with another data frame, that has numbers in the format tt0000008, tt0000012. For this I try to get the numbers fully, without omitting 0.

What would be the way to have full numbers like 0000008, 0000012, 0000091, 0000417?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend convert to `str` , then format with `pad` or `rjust`

```
s.astype(str).str.rjust(7,'0')
Out[168]: 
0    0000008
1    0000012
2    0000091
3    0000417
dtype: object
```